# How to statically link a library in order to build a shared library

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, udev

I am trying to build a shared library in Ubuntu Linux that depends on libusb.

I want to statically link in libusb into my shared library.

Now, so built libusb as a static lib.

Now, when I try to link it into my shared library, the linker gives an error saying that I should build libusb using the -fPIC flag.

Fair enough.

So I built libusb with -fPIC - but then I noticed that the size of the .so became significantly smaller presumably because it was no longer creating a static library.

But, I was able to successfully build my shared library with the -fPIC version of libusb.

But, when my application tries to load my shared library, the dynamic loader gives the following error:

symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: udev_new

Somehow, I want to statically link libusb into my shared library to avoid these types of symbol lookup errors but I can't find the right combination of gcc build options.

Can someone help sort this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that when you link in the libusb.a library, only symbols in libusb that is used in your shared library gets linked into your shared object.

To get around this, use the --whole-archive [linker](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) flag.
Instead of simply using `-lusb`, use

```
 -Wl,--whole-archive -lusb -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Comment: I'm not using -lusb.  I have built my own .a file from libusb source and I am linking to that in my cmake script.  target_link_libraries (xxx libusb-1.0.a)

Comment: Then you might run `make VERBOSE=1` to see which commands is being run. If instead of -lusb at the linking stage, the command just just states "libusb-1.0.a"  (possibly including a full path), you need to make cmake emit `-Wl,--whole-archive libusb-1.0.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive` instead - though I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I made cmake emit that but I still get the same error.  Note that I did not build libusb-1.0.a with -fPIC.

Comment: ok - I likely misread the unefined symbol you had too, `udev_new` , that's in the libudev library, not libusb, so you need to link your application with `-ludev` as well. Possibly you can get away with linking your shared library to `-ludev` too, albeit newer toolchains might disregard that and force you to use `-ludev` when linking your application - atleast without additional options.

Comment: I can't use -ludev because I want to be able to build x64, x86, and arm64 binaries from the same build machine (using different compilers).  So I have to build libusb with all generated code in that single static library so that I can use that to build my shared library.

Comment: well, since libusb requires libudev, you either link to -ludev, which you can do for both arm64 and x64_86 as long as you have the libudev library built for the respective architecture, or you embed libudev in your shared library like you did with libusb

Comment: I need to build an arm64 version of this on my x86_64 box.  But I am having a real hard time installing libudev-dev:arm64 on this box in order to enable this.  Can you help?